# PHP array with distinct elements (like Python set)

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a version of the PHP array class where all the elements must be distinct like, for instance, sets in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. You could fake it by using an associative array where the keys are the elements in the "set" and the values are ignored.

Comment: Note that this works only with strings and numbers, since these are the only legal types for array keys. You cannet have a 'set' of objects this way.

Comment: that's how it's routinely done in Lua.  of course, Lua tables can use any value as a key, instead of being arbitrarily limited to numbers and strings

Comment: How you accomplish something in Lua has nothing to do with how you do it in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a first-draft of an idea that could eventually work for what you want.

```
<?php

class DistinctArray implements IteratorAggregate, Countable, ArrayAccess
{
    protected $store = array();

    public function __construct(array $initialValues)
    {
        foreach ($initialValues as $key => $value) {
            $this[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    final public function offsetSet( $offset, $value )
    {
        if (in_array($value, $this->store, true)) {
            throw new DomainException('Values must be unique!');
        }

        if (null === $offset) {
            array_push($this->store, $value);
        } else {
            $this->store[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    final public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return $this->store[$offset];
    }

    final public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return array_key_exists($offset, $this->store);
    }

    final public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        unset( $this->store[$offset] );
    }

    final public function count()
    {
        return count($this->store);
    }

    final public function getIterator()
    {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->store);
    }
}

$test = new DistinctArray(array(
    'test' => 1,
    'foo'  => 2,
    'bar'  => 3,
    'baz'  => '1',
    8      => 4,
));

try {
    $test[] = 5;
    $test[] = 6;
    $test['dupe'] = 1;
}
catch (DomainException $e) {
  echo "Oops! ", $e->getMessage(), "<hr>";
}

foreach ($test as $value) {
    echo $value, '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a special class, or array_unique to filter the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

An array is an array, and for the most part yo can put anything into it. All keys must be unique. If you want to go and add a function that strips out duplicate values, that is very possible by simply doing a array_unique statement

Answer (score 1):

For objects that are not integers and strings: [SplObjectStorage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php)

> The SplObjectStorage class provides a map from objects to data or, by ignoring data, an object set.

Comment: Objects are never integer or strings. They are objects ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [Set class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ds-set.php). You can install with pecl

```
sudo pecl install ds
```

there is also [a polyfill](https://github.com/php-ds/polyfill) version available if u have no root access

```
composer require php-ds/php-ds
```

Answer (score 0):

In a basic way you could try `array_unique()`, maybe this could help to avoid duplicates in your array.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use array_unique.

If you use int and string values, `array_unique` uses a string-representation for comparison, so array `[1,'1','2']` will result in `[1,'2']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can trick

Array Key index are unique.

So you can store unique val as string keys, like a python set.

$liste , is just a bad exemple for simulate datas.

```php
$liste = ['1','1','2','3','4'];
$uniq = [];
for ($liste as elem) {
    $uniq[$elem] = 1;
}
$uniq = array_keys($uniq);
// Or use directly
for ($uniq as $uniqVal => $null) {
    echo $uniqVal;
}
```

Comment: It will not work if the values of the array are an object(or arrays), Because an object cannot be a key.

Comment: yes is true i was thinking about "string" keys